# Select aggregrate and date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, date-range

I can't figure this query out and it should be easy. But I'm at a loss.
How do you query using an aggregate SUM bound by a date range?

Given this table:

```
ID   EmployeeID PayAmount   PayDate
1    48         289.0000        2003-12-22 00:00:00.000
2    251        458.0000        2003-12-30 00:00:00.000
3    48         248.0000        2003-12-30 00:00:00.000
4    167        255.5000        2003-12-30 00:00:00.000
5    48         100.00          2004-01-31 00:00:00.000
6    251        100.00          2004-01-31 00:00:00.000
7    251        300.00          2004-02-14 00:00:00:000
```

I would like to run a query to see how much each employee earned during a given year.  So for 2003, the results would like this:

```
EmployeeID  TotalPaid 
48          537.00
167         255.50
251         458.00
```

For 2004 the results would be:

```
EmployeeID   TotalPaid
48           100.00
251          400.00
```

Comment: which dbms? is it sql server or oracle or mysql

Comment: What stops you from writing such queries yourself? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Microsoft SQl Server

Comment: I can't get the date range to work within the HAVING clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft SQL Server you can do like this.
Grouping the data based on the Year for each EmployeeID
The data can be filtered for a particular year using `HAVING` clause WITH `YEAR` function.
This query gives data for the year 2004

```
SELECT EmployeeID, 
       SUM(PayAmount) as TotalPaid, 
       DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR,0, Paydate), 0)  as Year
FROM Table1
GROUP BY EmployeeID, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR,0, Paydate), 0) 
HAVING YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR,0, Paydate), 0)) =2004
```

Comment: Maybe demonstrate how to use the date functions in a where clause to filter it for a particular year, as that seems to be part of where OP is hung up.

Comment: @TML, you are right, added the HAVING clause to demonstrate the year part.

Comment: Yes, sir.  That works.  I just added ORDER BY EmployeeID and it's exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Comment: Good suggestion to add the HAVING clause.  Thanks again!